# Contracting Fano divisors 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose we are given a smooth complex algebraic variety $X$ with a smooth, irreducible divisor $D$ such that $D$ is Fano and the normal bundle $L$ to $D$ is anti-ample.  Then we can contract $D$ to a point, at least in the category of complex analytic spaces.

Is the analytic isomorphism type of the singularity determined by $L$, or does it depend on higher order infinitesimal information of $D$ inside $X$?

Comment: The singularity depends on the normal bundle even if $D = \mathbb{P}^1$...

Comment: I meant it *only* depends on the normal bundle in my question;  for $\mathbb{P}^1$, you're saying it can depend on higher order information as well?  